# How to interpret the vw output with a -a (audit) option in the contextual bandit mode?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am running a contextual bandint approach to a 2 different sets which differ only in action variable. One set that I construct model on (klaster3.model) has 6 different action type, while the other set on which I also construct model (klaster8.model) has 7 different action type.

When I run such a line
`head testLabels -n 1 | vw -i klaster8.model -t -p /dev/stdout --quiet`
in a command line I get
`5.000000 Mloda_kobieta`
which looks like a choosen action from the policy for that context.

But when I try the same code with `-a` (audit) option I recieve such output:

`0.943965 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142055:1:0.50745        ^K:136407:1:0.236886    ^Young:101199:1:0.199628
0.994175 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142056:1:0.488827       ^K:136408:1:0.281023    ^Young:101200:1:0.224326
0.948740 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142057:1:0.482498       ^K:136409:1:0.2568      ^Young:101201:1:0.209442
0.979921 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142058:1:0.497253       ^K:136410:1:0.241421    ^Young:101202:1:0.241247
0.910945 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142059:1:0.506602       ^K:136411:1:0.208468    ^Young:101203:1:0.195875
1.004143 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142060:1:0.49813        ^K:136412:1:0.280554    ^Young:101204:1:0.225459
0.934807 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142061:1:0.494118       ^K:136413:1:0.240735    ^Young:101205:1:0.199954
0.953710 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142048:1:0.582269       ^K:136400:1:0.213502    ^Young:101192:1:0.15794
0.994442 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142049:1:0.526175       ^K:136401:1:0.243671    ^Young:101193:1:0.224595
0.944228 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142050:1:0.504455       ^K:136402:1:0.22308     ^Young:101194:1:0.216693
0.979964 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142051:1:0.521737       ^K:136403:1:0.233687    ^Young:101195:1:0.22454
0.907704 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142052:1:0.547686       ^Young:101196:1:0.186401        ^K:136404:1:0.173617
1.004132 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142053:1:0.549014       ^K:136405:1:0.247787    ^Young:101197:1:0.207331
0.937724 Mloda_kobieta
        Constant:142054:1:0.525254       ^K:136406:1:0.236784    ^Young:101198:1:0.175686
5.000000 Mloda_kobieta`

Which looks like some kind of scoring of actions for this context, and in my opinion the action with the  least scoring should be choosed (this is action 5 for this example). I am wondering why there are 14 rows, while I have only 7 different acion types in this data set? And why I recieve 12 rows when I have 6 different action types. It looks for me like number_of_different_acion_types*2. In my case there are only 2 explanatory variables, age and sex.

The questions are:

1) Does the number of rows in output with audit (-a) correspond to the equation: number_of_different_acion_types*number_of_explanatory_variables

2) If yes, does first 7 rows (in that example) correspond to first variable, and the other 7 to second variable?

3) How to get know what's the order of output? Which variable is treated as first and which as second? Does it correspond to the order of columns in an input dataset?

4) If the first 7 rows corresponds to the coefficients of costs for the 1st variable, and other 7 rows corresponds to the coefficients of costs for the 2nd variable,  does the output policy chooses the arm/action with the lowest sum of those coefficients? (Each action has 2 coefficients, because there are 2 variables).

I have suspicions that the order of output corresponds to the order of columns in input but I am not sure.

Thanks for answer.